# The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context is thrown when adding a user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I have read through a lot of posts in regards to this error, and the majority all say the same thing about it being about the connectionstring in the AppConfig, that it shouldn't be an EF connectionstring but a plain old sql connection string. I have made sure that the connectionstring is correct and that I am using a SQL Connection string but I still keep getting the error...
This is the code

```
public void RegisterDealer(RegisterAdministrator model)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.administratorName, Email = model.administratorEmail, AccountNumber = model.AccountNumber, LoginUserName = model.LoginUserName };

        ApplicationDbContext dbc = new ApplicationDbContext();

        PasswordHasher MyPasswordHash = new PasswordHasher();



        user.PasswordHash = MyPasswordHash.HashPassword(model.administratorPassword);
        user.SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        user.LockoutEnabled = true;
        user.AccountNumber = "1";
        user.IsActive = true;


        dbc.Users.Add(user);
        dbc.SaveChanges();

        AdvancewareIdentity ICE = new AdvancewareIdentity();
        AspNetUserRole AUR = new AspNetUserRole();

        AUR.UserId = user.Id;
        // Dealer RoleID
        // 8870ccb1-8ced-4703-a6bd-303c5ff5faf7

        AUR.RoleId = "8870ccb1-8ced-4703-a6bd-303c5ff5faf7";

        ICE.AspNetUserRoles.Add(AUR);
        ICE.SaveChanges();


        //UserManager.SendEmail(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + id + "\">here</a>");
    }
```

The error is right at

```
    dbc.Users.Add(user);
```

The StackTrace is this..

```
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.UpdateEntitySetMappingsForType(Type entityType)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ActOnSet(Action action, EntityState newState, Object entity, String methodName)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Add(Object entity)
at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Add(TEntity entity)
at AdvanceWareDAL.Authentication.AdministrationAccountController.RegisterDealer(RegisterAdministrator model) in c:\AdvanceWareRevision\AdvanceWareDAL\Authentication\AdministrationAccountController.cs:line 306
at AdvanceWareDAL.Authentication.OQOEDAL.AddNewDealer(NewDealer dealer) in c:\AdvanceWareRevision\AdvanceWareDAL\Models\OQOEDAL.cs:line 599
at AdvanceWareDAL.OQOEAdminstrationDAL.AddNewDealerFromAdministration(NewDealer dealer, String loggedinuser) in c:\AdvanceWareRevision\AdvanceWareDAL\OQOEAdminstrationDAL.cs:line 96
at AdvanceWareMVC.Controllers.AdministrationController.AddNewDealer(NewDealer dealer) in c:\AdvanceWareRevision\AdvanceWareMVC\Controllers\AdministrationController.cs:line 133
at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.<>c__DisplayClass1.<WrapVoidAction>b__0(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.ActionInvocation.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod()
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult](IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
```

Does anyone see something that I am missing or an idea on what to look at to resolve this issue?

**EDIT**

Here is the code for the DbContext

```
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("AdvancewareIdentity", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you post the code for ApplicationDbContext?

Comment: Does your ApplicationDbContext inherit from IdentityDbContext?

Comment: @Lidaranis, I added teh DbContext Code

Answer (score 1):

Your stacktrace is a mess. It looks like you're actually hitting this from an `AddNewDealer` action in `AdministrationController`, and from there, you're newing up an instance of `AdministrationAccountController` to call `RegisterDealer`, by way of jumping through your DAL, first. That at the very least means you've got no separation of concerns here, which is probably a large part of the problem.

Also, concerning is that there's no reference to where your context is coming from. Do each of these have their own version of the context? Nothing seems to allow injection of the dependency, so I would assume so. That's also problematic.

That said, based on the error, and the `ApplicationDbContext` you've posted, my best guess is that you've actually got two different context classes your application is working with, with the Identity user is one, and your other application data in the other. The error is the result of trying to associate the user instance with some other instance (likely `Dealer`) in a totally different context. Typically, Entity Framework would try to save you from yourself and attach the user to the other context, requiring a migration. Since that's not happening, I'd assume your second context is against an existing database where migrations have been disabled.

Long and short, any entities that need to be related to each other need to reside in the same context class. You can't mix and match. If you can't combine the contexts, then the best you can do is simply store the user id and use that to manually look up the user in your Identity context; you can't create a true foreign key or have a navigation property.

Comment: Everything went into a mess once i did housecleaning and restructuring, prior to that everything worked fine and you are correct I am using 2 different context classes. When you login its using the AccountController in my Framework.UI project, and when i go to register a new dealer, thats done in the DAL which holds the same Identity classes in a folder called Authentication. I know its a huge mess right now and I can't rewrite the whole project from scratch, so I need to work with whats been done

Comment: When I separated my DAL class into 2 different DAL classes, one called Admin and the other called Orders, then everything went bad

Comment: You need one context for your application. That can be in a class library, but not multiple class libraries. You'll have to pick one to be the master for your database.

Answer (score 0):

Creation through userManager should be much easier (Specific reason why you're not?). Following is how I solve this:

```
public void RegisterDealer(RegisterAdministrator model)
{
    ApplicationDbContext dbc = new ApplicationDbContext();

    var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.administratorName, Email = model.administratorEmail, AccountNumber = model.AccountNumber, LoginUserName = model.LoginUserName };
    user.SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    user.LockoutEnabled = true;
    user.AccountNumber = "1";
    user.IsActive = true;

    var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(dbc));

    UserManager.Create(user, "PasswordWithoutHash");
    dbc.SaveChanges();

    // Retrieve user to add to role
    var newUser = dbc.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Email == user.Email)       

    // If user created, add to the role
    if(newUser != null)
    {
        userManager.AddToRole(newUser.Id, "RoleName");
        dbc.SaveChanges();
    }

    //UserManager.SendEmail(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + id + "\">here</a>");
}
```

Comment: "PasswordWithoutHash", how does the password get hashed?

Comment: By a default PasswordHasher already present in Core framework.